# Why is this simple template class breaking in VS 2013 and not VS 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, visual-studio-2013

### Background

I recently began using VS 2013 with C# and decided to use it when I went to implement a simple heap with C++. I started framing out the heap class using a template parameter and started running into compilation errors... I have been writing templated code in VS2010 for a while and never ran into this problem until I tried compiling in VS2013.

The following code compiles and runs fine in Visual Studio 2010. It does not compile in Visual Studio 2013 and shows the following errors:

> 1>  Heap.inl 1>c:\users\knight\desktop\heap\heap\heap.inl(13): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
>
> 1>c:\users\knight\desktop\heap\heap\heap.inl(13): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
>
> 1>c:\users\knight\desktop\heap\heap\heap.inl(13): error C2059: syntax error : '<'
>
> 1>c:\users\knight\desktop\heap\heap\heap.inl(13): error C2039: 'Heap' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
>
> 1>c:\users\knight\desktop\heap\heap\heap.inl(19): error C2588: '::~Heap' : illegal global destructor
>
> 1>c:\users\knight\desktop\heap\heap\heap.inl(19): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation

Here is the Code:

### Heap.hpp

```
#ifndef HEAP_HPP
#define HEAP_HPP

namespace Knight
{
    template<class T>
    class Heap
    {
    private:
    public:
        //Default Constructor
        Heap();

        //Default destructor
        ~Heap();

        //Heapify
        //Add Element
        //Swim Element up
    };
}
#include "Heap.inl"
#endif // Heap_HPP
```

### Heap.inl

```
namespace Knight
{

    //NAME constructor
    template<typename T>
    Heap<T>::Heap()
    {
    }

    //NAME destructor
    template<typename T>
    Heap<T>::~Heap()
    {
    }

}
```

### What I tried to do

I looked at the microsoft site looking or breaking changes and did not see any that would pertain to what I am doing here. I am using the "separate definition and implementation" trick here and I am assuming something related to this broke.

I was hoping someone could help me out and tell me what changed from 2010-2013 that is causing this compilation issue.

Comment: For a test: Copy paste your Heap.inl code into Heap.hpp, remove #include "Heap.inl" and have only a single line #error ??? in your Heap.inl

Comment: Dont know why I didnt try experimenting with that. Copying the .inl into the .hpp made it compile.
So for some reason, it does not like including the .inl file into the header.

Comment: Heap.inl might compile separately (a second time)

Comment: I noticed the file type in VS was cpp/source. It should be "Document"
Changed it to Document and it still did not compile. So I removed the file from the project and re-added it and it works fine now. I believe I renamed the file to a .inl from a .cpp and VS2013 does not handle that too well. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed the file type in VS was cpp/source. It should be "Document" Changed it to Document and it still did not compile. So I removed the file from the project and re-added it and it works fine now. I believe I renamed the file to a .inl from a .cpp and VS2013 does not handle that too well. Problem solved once it is re-added and does not confuse it at CPP source.